# How to make a PHP variable loop in template

Tags: php, templates, template-engine

I am trying to make something so it shows the database results. The problem is, it only shows 1 result. I want it to show multiple results using an quick and dirty template system. Also, is there a way to make my system better? Perhaps a class or a function? I need some insight on this. Thanks a bunch!

cp.php

```
<?php
require("db.php");
chdir("../"); // path to MyBB
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require("./global.php");
$title = "********";
require("templates/header.php");

if($mybb->user['uid'])
{
    $uid = $mybb->user['uid'];
    // Active Tournaments
    // run queries, do all the brainwork
    // lets get the forum name
    $query = "SELECT tourneys.name, tourneys.date, tourneys.time
            FROM tourneys
            INNER JOIN players ON players.tid = tourneys.id
            WHERE players.forumname = {$uid}";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $activetournaments = "<td>". $row['name'] ."</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>". $row['time'] ."</td>";
        // $team = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tourneys WHERE id=" . $row['tid'] . "");
        // $playing = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `` FROM tourneys WHERE id=" . $row['tid'] . "");
    }
}
else
{
        $error = "Only registered members may access this area.";
        include ('templates/error.php');
}
require ("templates/cp.php")
?>
```

templates/cp.php

```
<h2>Welcome back <?=$mybb->user['username']; ?>!</h2>
<?=$postrequirement?>
<h3>Active Tournaments</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date/time</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Playing as</th>
    <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?=$activetournaments?>
    </table>
<hr />
<h3>Participated Tournaments</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date/time</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Played as</th>
    <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?=$participatedtournaments?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed $activetournaments to append to the end using '.='.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $activetournaments .= "<td>". $row['name'] ."</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>". $row['time'] ."</td> ";
}
```

At the moment, for each record, it is overwriting $activetournaments. You could also use $activetournaments as an array then do a while / foreach in the template.

Answer (score 0):

In your cp.php you overwrite `$activetournaments` in each while execution, change your code to:

```
<?php
require("db.php");
chdir("../"); // path to MyBB
define("IN_MYBB", 1);
require("./global.php");
$title = "1ShotGG Tournaments | Control Panel";
require("templates/header.php");

if($mybb->user['uid'])
{
    $uid = $mybb->user['uid'];
    // Active Tournaments
    // run queries, do all the brainwork
    // lets get the forum name
    $query = "SELECT tourneys.name, tourneys.date, tourneys.time
            FROM tourneys
            INNER JOIN players ON players.tid = tourneys.id
            WHERE players.forumname = {$uid}";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    // output data of each row

    $activetournaments = '';

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $activetournaments .= "<td>". $row['name'] ."</td><td>" . $row['date'] . "</td><td>". $row['time'] ."</td>";
        // $team = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM tourneys WHERE id=" . $row['tid'] . "");
        // $playing = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `` FROM tourneys WHERE id=" . $row['tid'] . "");
    }
}
else
{
        $error = "Only registered members may access this area.";
        include ('templates/error.php');
}
require ("templates/cp.php")
?>
```

In your templates/cp.php you can add a `</tr>` tag here:

```
<tr>
    <?=$activetournaments?>
</tr>
```

your new templates/cp.php:

```
<h2>Welcome back <?=$mybb->user['username']; ?>!</h2>
<?=$postrequirement?>
<h3>Active Tournaments</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date/time</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Playing as</th>
    <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?=$activetournaments?>
</tr>
    </table>
<hr />
<h3>Participated Tournaments</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date/time</th>
    <th>Team</th>
    <th>Played as</th>
    <th>Options</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <?=$participatedtournaments?>
    </table>
```